# Report builder not executing complete SQL query

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

I'm working with a SQL query which has around 900 lines, I have copied the entire SQL query and pasted in report builder to develop a report. But,the report builder taking only 500 lines of the query remaining 400 lines are not visible or missing.

Does report builder have any limitations with lines? How can I deal with this?

Comment: That's a very long run-on sentence you got there.

Comment: I'm not getting what you are saying..

Comment: Nor will anyone get what you're saying if you can't use punctuation better.

Answer (score 0):

Report Builder does not have a specific limit on the number of lines in a SQL query. In fact is was designed to handle large queries

If your query appears to be cut off, it might be a display or formatting issue.

Use the scrollbar to navigate through the entire query.
Properly format your queries with line breaks for better readability.